# C - writing a multi-threaded program to square numbers

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that uses multiple threads to compute the squares of numbers between 1-10000. I am trying to get each thread to square one number at a time, with a maximum of 8 threads. This means that threads 1-8 will square 8 numbers, and as they finish they begin squaring the next number, etc.

My code compiles without error, but does not print anything to the output file. I can't exactly pinpoint the issue, so could someone give me some tips or point me in the right direction?

Also, for those who provide code to help, I have commented sections that I would rather not be altered. I doubt they would need to anyway, but I am using them for other parts of this project and would like to keep them the same.
Thanks. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8
#define START_NUMBER 1
#define END_NUMBER 10000

FILE *f;

void *sqrtfunc(void *tid) { //function for computing squares
    int i;
    for (i = START_NUMBER; i<=END_NUMBER; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%lu squared = %lu\n", i, i*i);
    }
}

int main(){
    //Do not modify starting here
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, 0);
    long unsigned i;
    f = fopen("./squared_numbers.txt", "w");
    //Do not modify ending here

    pthread_t mythreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; //thread variable
    long mystatus;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){ //loop to create 8 threads
        mystatus = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, sqrtfunc, (void *)i);
        if (mystatus != 0){ //check if pthread_create worked
            printf("pthread_create failed\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
        if(pthread_join(mythreads[i], NULL)){
            printf("Thread failed\n");
        }
    }
    exit(1);

    //Do not modify starting here
    fclose(f);
    gettimeofday(&end_time, 0);
    float elapsed = (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + \
                    (end_time.tv_usec-start_time.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
    printf("took %0.2f milliseconds\n", elapsed);
    //Do not modify ending here
}
```

The only solution I can think of is moving the for-loop that creates the 8 threads and placing it inside of the sqrtfunc function's for-loop. Would this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, all threads are fighting for the same file.

Comment: @user3528438 Can you give me a hint on how to resolve this? Shouldn't they be able to print to it when I do `pthread_create`?

Comment: I suggest adding some error handling, e.g. to check whether fopen is successful or not. I have tested your code and it printed the following output in the file. 1 squared = 1
2 squared = 4
3 squared = 9 ......9998 squared = 99960004
9999 squared = 99980001
10000 squared = 100000000
4 squared = 16
...
9 squared = 81
10 squared = 100

Comment: even they if were able print to it will look this like

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`

Comment: the top level thread function needs to have either a `return (void*)&status;`  or (better)  `pthread_exit( &status )  note `status could be NULL

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code will, in the threads, always square the same numbers 1...10000. I thought you were trying to spread the load, not make each thread perform the whole load

Comment: in this function: `void *sqrtfunc(void *tid)` the parameter `tid` is not used. This will cause the compiler to raise a warning.  Suggest inserting a  statement in the function: `(void)tid;`

Comment: due to this line: `exit(1);`, the calculation of the elapsed time and printing of that value will never be executed.  Is that what you actually want?

Comment: the code contains some 'race' conditions where each thread is trying to write to the same file.  This results in a significant mixing of the output lines from the various theads

Comment: in the `sqrtfunc()`,  the variable `i`  should be declared as `size_t i;` rather than `int i;`  so it will match the `%lu` format specifiers in the `fprintf()` statement.

Comment: to get each thread to only square a specific number on any one iteration. suggest a `mutex`  for access to a number in the global file space,  each thread calls `mutex_lock()`, gets the current value of the global variable, increments the global variable, calls `mutex_unlock()` if the global variable was > 10000, the exits the thread otherwise performs the square, fprintf(), then loops to do it again.   HOWEVER, due to the race conditions, the numbers in the output file are no likely to be all sequential

Comment: you might want to read this web page: (much to large to post) `http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/` for details and examples on how to use the `pthread_mutex_lock()` and related functions.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problem with threads fight for file access each thread can return result which will be put to file by main process. Or thread can prepare result string and lock before writing to file just this string. Below is first solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8
#define START_NUMBER 1
#define END_NUMBER 1000

FILE* f;

struct Thread_argument
{
    unsigned long long start;
    int range;
};

void* sqrtfunc( void* a ) //function for computing squares
{
    struct Thread_argument* argument = ( struct Thread_argument* )a;
    unsigned long long* result = calloc( argument->range, sizeof( unsigned long long ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < argument->range; i++ )
    {
        result[i] = ( argument->start + i ) * ( argument->start + i );
    }

    free( a );
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    //Do not modify starting here
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday( &start_time, 0 );
    long unsigned i;
    f = fopen( "./squared_numbers.txt", "w" );
    //Do not modify ending here
    pthread_t mythreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; //thread variable
    long mystatus;
    int END = END_NUMBER + 1;
    int const range = ( END - START_NUMBER ) / ( NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++ ) //loop to create 8 threads
    {
        struct Thread_argument* ta = malloc( sizeof( struct Thread_argument ) );
        ta->start = i * range + START_NUMBER;
        ta->range = range;

        if( i == NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 )
        {
            ta->range = ( END - START_NUMBER ) % ( NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 );
        }

        mystatus = pthread_create( &mythreads[i], NULL, sqrtfunc, ( void* )ta );

        if( mystatus != 0 ) //check if pthread_create worked
        {
            printf( "pthread_create failed\n" );
            exit( -1 );
        }
    }

    unsigned long long* results[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; //thread variable

    for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        if( pthread_join( mythreads[i], ( void** )&results[i] ) )
        {
            printf( "Thread failed\n" );
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < range; ++j )
        {
            fprintf( f, "%d %lld\n", i * range + j + START_NUMBER, results[ i ][ j ] );
        }

        free( results[ i ] );
    }

    int leftovers = ( END - START_NUMBER ) % ( NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < leftovers; ++i )
    {
        fprintf( f, "%d %lld\n", ( NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 ) * range + i + 1, results[ NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 ][ i ] );
    }

    free( results[ NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1 ] );
    fclose( f );
    //Do not modify starting here
    gettimeofday( &end_time, 0 );
    float elapsed = ( end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec ) * 1000.0f + \
                    ( end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec ) / 1000.0f;
    printf( "took %0.2f milliseconds\n", elapsed );
    //Do not modify ending here
    return 0;
}
```