# Squaring numbers with multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to square the numbers 1 - 10,000 with 8 threads. To clarify, I want the 1st thread to do 1^2, 2nd thread to do 2^2, ..., 8th thread to do 8^2, first thread to do 9^2... etc. The problem I am having is that instead of the above happening, each thread computes the squares of 1-10,000.

My code is below. I have marked sections that I'd rather those answering do not modify. Thanks in advance for any tips!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8
#define START_NUMBER 1
#define END_NUMBER 10000

FILE *f;

void *sqrtfunc(void *tid) { //function for computing squares
    int i;
    for (i = START_NUMBER; i<=END_NUMBER; i++){
        fprintf(f, "%lu squared = %lu\n", i, i*i);
    }
}

int main(){
    //Do not modify starting here
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, 0);
    long unsigned i;
    f = fopen("./squared_numbers.txt", "w");
    //Do not modify ending here

    pthread_t mythreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; //thread variable
    long mystatus;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){ //loop to create 8 threads
        mystatus = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, sqrtfunc, (void *)i);
        if (mystatus != 0){ //check if pthread_create worked
            printf("pthread_create failed\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
        if(pthread_join(mythreads[i], NULL)){
            printf("Thread failed\n");
        }
    }
    exit(1);

    //Do not modify starting here
    fclose(f);
    gettimeofday(&end_time, 0);
    float elapsed = (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + \
                    (end_time.tv_usec-start_time.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
    printf("took %0.2f milliseconds\n", elapsed);
    //Do not modify ending here
}
```

Comment: How does each thread know which numbers it should/should not work with?

Comment: You need to modify the for loop inside sqrtfunc() so it handles a different subset of the total-work-to-be-done, based on the value of (tid).  I won't say more since I suspect this may be homework.

Comment: Each thread should compute the range to calculate of be passed one instead of the fixed one.

Comment: That's what I'm stuck on. I need threads 1-8 to square numbers 1-8, and then when thread 1 is available again it squares 9, and so on.

Comment: You are aware a single context switch can easily take more cycles than an optimised single threaded version, are you? And printing to the file without synchronisation is guarantee for a race condition.

Comment: @Olaf yes I am aware

Comment: @JeremyFriesner so I should divide it up so thread 1 does 1-1250, 2 does 1251-2500, etc?

Comment: @donutjuice So in other words, each thread squares every 8th number, starting from its thread number (1-8)? So thinking about it one thread at a time, you want to square numbers 1, 9, 17, 25, etc. How would you write a loop to do that?

Comment: @immibis the first thing that comes to my head is doing a for-loop for i from 1-10,000 and doing i%8 to figure out which thread should square the number. Can this be condensed any more?

Comment: @donutjuice You can't think of a way to skip ahead 8 numbers at a time instead of 1?

Comment: @donutjuice that would work fine.  The other way to do it would be to interleave accesses so that thread 1 does item #2, thread 2 does item #2, and so on, but you'll get better performance if you give each thread a contiguous sub-block (because that way the cores on the CPU will be accessing contiguous memory, and also less likely to invalidate each other's cache lines)

Comment: Isn't this question kind of duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677805/c-writing-a-multi-threaded-program-to-square-numbers/35682803#35682803