# Squaring numbers w/ multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that squares numbers 1-10,000 by creating 8 threads and each thread will take turns squaring ONE NUMBER EACH. Meaning that one thread will square 1, another will square 2, etc until all threads square a number. Then one thread will square 9, etc, all the way to 10,000. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8
#define START_NUMBER 1
#define END_NUMBER 10000

FILE *f;

void *sqrtfunc(void *tid) { //function for computing squares
    int i;
    for (i = START_NUMBER; i<= END_NUMBER; i++){
        if ((i % NUMBER_OF_THREADS) == pthread_self()){ //if i%8 == thread id
            fprintf(f, "%lu squared = %lu\n", i, i*i); //then that thread should do this
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    //Do not modify starting here
    struct timeval start_time, end_time;
    gettimeofday(&start_time, 0);
    long unsigned i;
    f = fopen("./squared_numbers.txt", "w");
    //Do not modify ending here

    pthread_t mythreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; //thread variable
    long mystatus;

    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){ //loop to create 8 threads
        mystatus = pthread_create(&mythreads[i], NULL, sqrtfunc, (void *)i);
        if (mystatus != 0){ //check if pthread_create worked
            printf("pthread_create failed\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++){
        if(pthread_join(mythreads[i], NULL)){
            printf("Thread failed\n");
        }
    }
    exit(1);

    //Do not modify starting here
    fclose(f);
    gettimeofday(&end_time, 0);
    float elapsed = (end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + \
                    (end_time.tv_usec-start_time.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
    printf("took %0.2f milliseconds\n", elapsed);
    //Do not modify ending here
}
```

I am not sure where my error is. I create my 8 threads in main, and then depending on their thread id (tid), I want that thread to square a number. As of right now, nothing is being printed into the output file and I can't figure out why. Is my tid comparison not doing anything? Any tips are appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: What makes you think a `pthread_t` is an arithmetic type?

Comment: @EOF I don't have much experience with making programs multithreaded so I'm not sure. I am trying to access thread ID's, can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: You cannot use the tid like that. From the [`pthread_self` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html): "variables of type pthread_t can't portably be compared using the C equality operator (==). Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use thread ID other than in pthreads calls is nonportable and can lead to
unspecified results."

Comment: A better approach is to explicitly pass in a value to the thread via the `arg` in `pthread_create`. Which you are doing but are not using in the thread code.

Comment: @kaylum so I should totally scrap the idea? Or is there a way to work around that?

Comment: You're already passing an `int` cast to a `void *` to the function via `pthread_create()`. You could cast the `void *` back to `int`, increment it by `NUMBER_OF_THREADS` each time in the loop and square the result. Note that the casts are not gauranteed to round-trip.

Comment: Deja-vu :( .........................

Comment: Isn't this a kinda duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690653/squaring-numbers-with-mutliple-threads

Comment: @kaylum can you provide an example?  I tried comparing sqrtfunc's arg (void *tid) but i'm getting uncompatible pointer type. I also tried &tid in the comparison and that didn't work either.

Comment: The first line of your `sqrtfunc` can be: `int thread_id = (int) tid`. And then use `thread_id` in place of `pthread_self`. But be aware that  casting from a pointer to an `int` is not technically correct as they can be different sizes. But it should work in your case. The more correct way is to have an array of `int` values and pass a pointer to an array entry to each thread.

Comment: Is this a thread exercise or a squaring exercise? You don't even need to multiply, just 2 additions. `4 - 1 = 3`, `9 - 4 = 5`, `16 - 9 = 7`, `25 - 16 = 9` etc, you get the sequence. So each square is 2 more than the previous difference.

Comment: @WeatherVane thread exercise..

Comment: @kaylum just tried this and got `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size`. Is there no easier way to compare an integer to a thread id?

Comment: No you can't use the thread id as an integer at all. I did tell you about that warning already. If you want to get rid of it then you need to set up the array as I described.

Answer (score 0):

First, you intentionally pass a parameter to each thread so it know which thread it is (from 0 to 7) That is good, but you then don't use it anymore inside the thread (this leads to one of the possible confussions you have)

Second, as you say in the explanation of how the algorithm should go, you say each thread must square a different set of numbers, but all of them **do square the same set of numbers** (indeed the whole set of numbers)

You have two approaches to this:  Let each thread square the number, and go for the next, eight places further (so the algorithm is the one described in your explanation) or you give different sets (each 1250 consecutive numbers) and let each thread act on is own separate interval.

That said, you have to reconstruct your `for` loop to do one of two:

```
for (i = parameter; i < MAX; i += 8) ...
```

or

```
for (i = 1250*parameter; i < 1250*(parameter+1); i++) ...
```

that way, you'll get each thread run with a different set of input numbers.